# Not all MBean available in Confluence

Tags: jmx, confluence, mbeans

I have confluence 5.10.6 on tomcat 8. 
In tomcat I have setup jmx:

> CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=6969  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false ${CATALINA_OPTS}"

and using jconsole trying to have access to Confluence MBeans.
Unfortunately only several of MBeans available:

- CacheStatistics
- IndexingStatistics
- MailTaskQueue
- SchedulingStatistics
- SystemInformation

But I need also RequestMetrics (https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/live-monitoring-using-the-jmx-interface-150274182.html).

What I missed in my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is perfectly fine.

The missing RequestMetrics MBean is actually a known bug in Confluence since 5.9.2: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-40442

You can vote for this issue there to raise awareness by Atlassian.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same MBeans, in my evaluation version of the confluence.

I have a "confluense.jar" file with "jmxContext.xml" inside.
jmxContext.xml (it contains a reference to  **MBeanExporterWithUnregisterImpl** implementaion) :

```
  <bean id="exporter" class="com.atlassian.confluence.jmx.MBeanExporterWithUnregisterImpl">
      <constructor-arg index="0" ref="eventPublisher"/>
      <constructor-arg index="1" ref="tenantAccessor"/>
      <property name="server" ref="mbeanServer"/>
      <property name="beans">
          <map>
                <entry key="Confluence:name=MailTaskQueue">
                    <bean class="com.atlassian.confluence.jmx.TaskQueueWrapper"><constructor-arg
                            ref="mailTaskQueue"/></bean>
                </entry>
              <entry key="Confluence:name=IndexingStatistics">
                    <bean class="com.atlassian.confluence.jmx.JmxIndexManagerWrapper"><constructor-arg
                            ref="indexManager"/></bean>
                </entry>
              <entry key="Confluence:name=SchedulingStatistics">
                    <bean class="com.atlassian.confluence.jmx.JmxScheduledTaskWrapper"><constructor-arg
                            ref="scheduler"/></bean>
                </entry>
              <entry key="Confluence:name=SystemInformation">
                    <bean class="com.atlassian.confluence.jmx.JmxSystemInfoWrapper"><constructor-arg
                            ref="systemInformationService"/></bean>
                </entry>
              <entry key="Confluence:name=CacheStatistics">
                  <bean class="com.atlassian.confluence.jmx.JxmCacheStatisticsWrapper">
                      <constructor-arg ref="cacheStatisticsManager"/>
                  </bean>
              </entry>
          </map>
      </property>
      <property name="exposeManagedResourceClassLoader" value="true"/>
  </bean>
```

So, at least there is nothing wrong, because our installation does not support RequestMetrics mbean, and as far as we can see the RequestMetrics.class inside of confluence.jar, i believe it is a licensing issue.

Comment: I have licensed version. And before upgrade I had all MBeans, but after upgrade (I also reinstall BeanSpy and change tomcat configuration) - only part of MBeans available.

Comment: Could you look at your previous version of confluence.jar? Maybe they've forgot to include "RequestMetrics" entry to the xml, then you just can try to replace it (but do a backup of confluence.jar before), anyway it's like a hack, but it seemed there is no choice.